# insert icon beside title tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

I want to insert icon from input of icon beside title tab but it deos not work. what should i include to my code?

i want to be icon value that i will insert in shorcode.

```
    //Generate header
    $('#myTab>li').each(function(i,e){
        var $this = $(this);
        var title = $this.find('a:first').text();
        var icon = $('.active').find('.tab_icon').val();
        var href = $this.find('a:first').attr('href')+tid;
        var sclass = (i==0)?'active':'';
        if($this.hasClass('dropdown')){

          var id = $this.find('a:first').attr('id')+tid;
          shortcode+='[dropdown id="'+id+'" title="'+title+'"]<br class="nc"/>';

          var subcode = '';
          $(this).find('li').each(function(){
                var  shref=$(this).find('a').attr('href')+tid;
                var stitle=$(this).find('a').text();
               var sicon=$('.tab-pane').find('.tab-icon').val();

                subcode +='[tab type="tab" href="'+shref+'" title="'+stitle+
                '" icon="'+sicon+'"]<br class="nc"/>';

          });


          shortcode +=subcode;
          shortcode += '[/dropdown]<br class="nc"/>';

        }
        else{

    shortcode +='[tab type="tab" href="'+href+'" title="'+title+'" icon="'+icon+'"]<br class="nc"/>';
        }
    })


    shortcode += '[/thead][tcontents]<br class="nc"/>';
```

Comment: The proper way is to use a CSS background.

Comment: Diodeus is correct. Naheed, just out of interest, why are you building markup in script? It's frowned upon in normal circumstances, I just wondered what your reasoning was?